# R: Extra-space in label position. gplots - VennDiagram - venn.diagramm()

Tags: r, layout, venn-diagram

I'm facing this little layout problem here with this 3-vector list venn diagram. I specified cat.pos = c(0, 0, 0), cat.dist = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1) to have all 3 labels at noon above their respective area and at the same distance but I got the 3rd 1 step more above..
It is also farther when no cat.dist vector is passed to the function.

```
# Get gene lists to do Venn diagram
ids_3883_pvsUNR <- c(paste0("gene",c(1:66)))
ids_3883_pvsCRSP <- c(paste0("gene",c(67:126)))
ids_3884 <- c(paste0("gene",c(1:30,67:85,1001:4054)))

head(ids_3883_pvsUNR)

length(ids_3883_pvsUNR)
length(ids_3883_pvsCRSP)
length(ids_3884)


# 
geneLS <- list(ids_3883_pvsUNR, ids_3883_pvsCRSP, ids_3884)
# We can rename our list vectors
names(geneLS) <- c("Set_1_3883_pvsUNR","Set_1_3883_pvsCRSP", "Set_2_3884RUV")

# Now we can plot a Venn diagram with the VennDiagram R package, as follows:
require("VennDiagram")

VENN.LIST <- geneLS
labels <- c("Set_1_3883\nPat 1,2 vs UNR","Set_1_3883\nPat 1,2 vs 3 CRSP", "Set_2_3884RUV\nPat 3 vs 3 CRSP")
venn.plot <- venn.diagram(VENN.LIST , NULL, fill=c("darkmagenta", "darkblue", "grey"), alpha=c(0.5,0.5,0.5), cex = 2, cat.fontface=4, cat.pos = c(0, 0, 0), cat.dist = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1), category.names=labels, main="Set_1_May_3883 (P vs UNR or CRSP) vs Set_2_May_3884_RUVcorrected")

# To plot the venn diagram we will use the grid.draw() function to plot the venn diagram
dev.off()
grid.draw(venn.plot)
```

Does somebody know what is happening here?
Thanks for your feedback!
Daniel

[image: extra space in label 3 <-> area despite same distance given in parameters]

Comment: Please provide a reproducible dataset next time, as it is difficult to understand what exactly is going on here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Comment: Alright yes, I did not think of copying the code with gene1... etc to allow reproducibility without access to the actual data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the functions of the `ggVennDiagram` or `ggvenn` package.
Here are the data

```
genes <- paste("gene",1:3180,sep="")
x <- list(
  `Set_1_3883\n Pat 1,2 vs UNR` = genes[1:66], 
  `Set_1_3883\n Pat 1,2 vs 3 CRSP` = genes[37:3139], 
  `Set_2_3884RUV\n Pat 3 vs 3 CRSP` = genes[3121:3180]
)
```

And now the graph

```
library(ggVennDiagram)
ggVennDiagram(x, label_alpha = 0)+
  scale_fill_gradient(low="gray",high = "blue")
```

[image]

And with the `ggvenn` package

```
library(ggvenn)
ggvenn(
  x, 
  fill_color = c("plum1", "blueviolet", "gray"),
  stroke_size = 0.5, set_name_size = 4
)
```

[image]

In both cases they are ggplots so you will have much better control over them.

Comment: Thank you very much Marek, indeed i'll go on with learning ggplot2 that is better that the piece of code I had found to do my plot in the meantime.

Comment: Use ggplot whenever possible. It is well documented and allows for very flexible adjustment of the charts to the expected form. If you think that my answer is correct, please accept.